# Sending Text / Email to Smartphone from web page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, sms

I have a web page which holds a link the some other mobile page.
I would like to be able to send this link to the user's mobile phone, so that the user can visit it.

I want to send a link to the user's mobile phone

What are my options?

Comment: No, I want to send a link to the user's mobile phone

Comment: There are various commercial SMS gateway products that can be accessed from PHP, but even aside from the potential cost of the products themselves I would expect you'd have to pay per text (or per x number of texts) or accept an ad-supported service given that ultimately you're interfacing with the phone network and phone companies never give away anything for free. As far as sending emails, I'm not sure that you can specifically target a smartphone, but of course your users can choose to read email from their smartphone. Have you Googled this yet?

Answer (score 1):

Subscribe with some operator or SMS gateway and use their API.
Have a look at this link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_gateway
and look at this search results
http://bit.ly/sMob77